# Are Instagram Real-time Updates limited to images that are public?

Tags: instagram

We are trying to do a "proof of concept" to leverage Instagram to promote customer loyalty. So for example, you upload a picture at our store with our #companyhashtag and you receive some added reward to your account.

I've gotten a tag subscription to work, I tested it with the company user uploading a picture and tagging it. The company user is public.

Then I tested it with my personal account, and it does not trigger an update. I tried the following to see if it would get Instagram to use my subscription callback with now success:

1. Requested to follow my private account from company account, and granted the "Follow"
2. Tagged the picture uploaded from my private account not only with the subscribed #tag but tagged the company user in the photo

I have read the [Authentication](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) documentation in the API, but I think it would be too much for what we are trying to achieve.

First of all I would like to confirm if the real-time subscriptions are limited to "public" state users.

If beyond that anyone has insights that might add depth to the question or answer, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would go as far as to say yes, this would only work for public images.

say for instance your account is private so you only want to make your pictures available to people you've allowed. You then don't want some random API application to get hold of your images and then be able to serve them online where ever they want.

Comment: I totally agree. But if, for example, that private user has tagged the user to which the client_id pertains to, then you should be able to see it. What I'm trying to get at, is there should be a way to have limited access through the API to a private users photos without it having to be an all (app authorization) or none proposition, both seem to extreme...